# Old PC Linux & Flash

Tags: flash

Ive got a few old towers lying around with integrated graphics & the following CPUS

Sempron 2600+

Sempron 2800+

Sempron 3400+

Athlon LE1620

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 and tried to watch a flash video on Filmon.com and on youtube and it instantly maxes the CPU out and it jutters along.

Would a different linux make a difference? If so what do you recommend
Or do I need a graphics card to help the CPU along?

Or is flash just doomed to not work on any of these CPUs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use either `xubuntu` or `lubuntu`.They don't use CPU as much as ubuntu does.

Comment: Lubuntu is quite lighter than Xubuntu, so my advice is to give it a try.